# How to subset data based on numerical criteria in column names in R?

Tags: r

**Problem:** I have time-series data that I would like to subset based on a start and end time which is different for each row. Each of the time points has a value per row (e.g. in columns "value_1" through "value_5").

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(101, 102, 103, 104, 105),
                 start = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 2),
                 end = c(2, 4, 3, 4, 3),
                 value_1 = c(8, 10, 4, 7, 6),
                 value_2 = c(3, 6, 9, 2, 5),
                 value_3 = c(4, 4, 10, 1, 6),
                 value_4 = c(5, 7, 8, 9, 2),
                 value_5 = c(4, 6, 3, 8, 10))
df

#    ID start end value_1 value_2 value_3 value_4 value_5
# 1 101     1   2       8       3       4       5       4
# 2 102     2   4      10       6       4       7       6
# 3 103     1   3       4       9      10       8       3
# 4 104     3   4       7       2       1       9       8
# 5 105     2   3       6       5       6       2      10
```

**Goal:** I would like to create a data frame that only returns values for columns between the start and end times (inclusive) for each row, and returns NAs for any rowwise values outside the start and end times, as such:

```
#    ID start end value_1 value_2 value_3 value_4 value_5
# 1 101     1   2       8       3      NA      NA      NA
# 2 102     2   4      NA       6       4       7      NA
# 3 103     1   3       4       9      10      NA      NA
# 4 104     3   4      NA      NA       1       9      NA
# 5 105     2   3      NA       5       6      NA      NA
```

I am honestly not sure what route to take in trying to solve this problem, so I look forward to any ideas. This is my first time asking a question here, so if you need more info or if something is confusing, let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can reshape to 'long' format and then convert it back after the transformation

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   pivot_longer(starts_with('value')) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(value = replace(value,
           !row_number() %in% first(start):first(end), NA)) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
# A tibble: 5 x 8
#     ID start   end value_1 value_2 value_3 value_4 value_5
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1   101     1     2       8       3      NA      NA      NA
#2   102     2     4      NA       6       4       7      NA
#3   103     1     3       4       9      10      NA      NA
#4   104     3     4      NA      NA       1       9      NA
#5   105     2     3      NA       5       6      NA      NA
```

---

Or in `base R` with `apply`

```
df[-1] <-  t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) {
     x[-(1:2)] <- replace(x[-(1:2)], !seq_along(x[-(1:2)]) %in% x[1]:x[2], NA)
     x}))
```